# android vcs file does not open when downloaded from azure storage

Tags: android, azure-storage, icalendar

I have a **`php`** file that contains a `vCalendar` format.

Here is how it is built:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/x-vCalendar');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=event.php');
?>
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
// some required text is here for the calendar to display the appointment
END:VCALENDAR
```

**The problem is this:**

When I download the file (to Android phone) from the folders in my Azure website - It works!
When I save the SAME file in azure storage and download it  - It doesn't work!

Have tried all different MIME types but still no luck. Anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Content-type:text/calendar
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=event.**ics**

Comment: Nope. It stills only downloads the file but Android is unable to read it. This is getting stranger... I simply can not explain this behavior

Comment: Perhaps if you could post the file, or a link to the file ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change header type

header("Content-Type: text/x-vCalendar");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=myevent.vcs");